# Macro for adding a column with a specific header and populating a default value in all rows

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I have a requirement to add a new column next to the last header cell with data and fill the new column with some random value say "Cool !" in a given worksheet.

Below is my macro:

```
Sub sbInsertingColumns(sourceFile As String, Worksheet As String)
Dim lastColName As String
Dim LastColumn As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastColumn = Workbooks(sourceFile).Worksheets(Worksheet).Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    End With
    Dim nextCell As Integer
    nextCell = Val(LastColumn) + Val(1)

    lastColName = Replace(Replace(Cells(1, nextCell).Address, "1", ""), "$", "")
    Workbooks(sourceFile).Worksheets(Worksheet).Range(lastColName & 1).Value = "New Header"
    MsgBox "New Column has been added : [ " & lastColName & 1 & "]"
End Sub
```

Adding values :

```
Sub Add()
    Dim cellVal As String
    Dim cell As Range
    cellVal = .Range("E")
    For Each cell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E:e").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
        cell.Value = "Cool !"
    Next cell
End Sub
```

I can able to add a new column with some header , but the above logic for adding value into the new column is not working. Can anyone please help me out.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub sbInsertingColumns(sourceFile As String, Worksheet As String)

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Workbooks(sourceFile).Worksheets(Worksheet)

    With sht.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)
        Application.Intersect(sht.UsedRange.EntireRow, .EntireColumn).Value = "Cool !"
        .Value = "New Header"
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go like follows:

```
Sub sbInsertingColumns(sourceFile As String, sheetName As String, headerName As String)
    With Workbooks(sourceFile).Worksheets(sheetName).UsedRange
        With .Columns(.Columns.Count).Offset(, 1)
            .Value = "Cool !"
            .Cells(1, 1) = headerName
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

to be used by some "main" sub as follows:

```
Sub main()
    sbInsertingColumns ActiveWorkbook.Name, ActiveSheet.Name, "newheader"
End Sub
```

you can also shorten down your parameters list as follows:

```
Sub sbInsertingColumns(ws As Worksheet, headerName As String)
    With ws.UsedRange
        With .Columns(.Columns.Count).Offset(, 1)
            .Value = "Cool"
            .Cells(1, 1) = headerName
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

and call it like follows

```
Sub main()
    sbInsertingColumns ActiveSheet, "newheader"
End Sub
```